# Streaming Mongodb documents with reference population to the client (using Node.js): any good algorithm principles?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, stream, populate

## The context

The web client request data (documents), sometime those documents should be populated by other documents. The whole dataset is sent to the browser using JSON.

**Technologies involved:** mongodb, node.js, various browsers.

## tl;dr

The original algorithm was designed to be as fast as possible, but was **not** designed to support huge dataset: no streaming, everything is loaded in memory, populated, then sent to the browser.

Too bad: users tend to use the app in an unexpected way, for unexpected use cases, so many requests involve huge dataset, and that consume too much memory.

The current algorithm should be dropped in favor of another one featuring streaming.

**However streaming and populating documents efficiently is really challenging.**

*Deep population* can eventually happen too (population of population) in this app.

## The complete story

The current algorithm (without streaming) is fast and nice to the database: optimal DB round-trip, and not a single document is requested twice for the same client request.

- the first DB round-trip get all *top-level* documents
- if population is involved (most of time), they are scanned, and reference (ID+collection) are stored, IDs of documents already *loaded* are excluded, and another DB round-trip is performed, and each DB reference is replaced by the actual document
- if *deep population* is involved, the previous step is done again and again, until there is nothing more to populate or until the depth limit is reached (usually: 2)
- the whole dataset is passed to JSON.stringify(), and sent to the browser

This model was working well until users started using the app for use cases we haven't thought of. The number of top-level documents per client request was at most 100 or 150. Now some requests reclaim up to 5000 top-level documents, as a result the memory consumption of the server-side application is high.

Now the new algorithm should:

- use streaming without retaining any data in memory
- output data to the browser using a JSON stream format

Streaming data without population is easy, since mongodb's cursors are stream-compliant.

However I can't think of a decent way to optimize document's population anymore. We definitively can't perform a DB round-trip for each document, and once the document is sent, of course, it is too late to populate it.

The alternate way is a mix of two: get a chunk of at most 100 documents to retain in memory, populate them, send them to the browser, get the next chunks, etc...

Another alternative would be to simply not populate document:

- use a JSON stream format
- stream documents directly to the client, retain only DB ref in memory for population
- perform another DB round-trip for each depth of population, streaming those new documents to the user
- when everything is done, send a final trailing JSON containing data explaining how the documents are related
- let the client-side application restructure the dataset

**Any ideas?**

Comment: Hey cronvel, I would say you're not using the right tool for the job. Since you want to populate your data and you're using MongoDB (which isn't optimal for relational data) meanwhile you stream it, you *have* to keep a buffer of the document you're currently populating in-memory, essentially "pausing" the stream until it's been populated. Instead you should use a database that offers this kind of functionality, like a relational database such as [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) or a multi-model database such as [ArangoDB](https://www.arangodb.com/) (documents, graph, key-value)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. BTW switching database is not an option for us ATM. Also, if relational database can achieve the "populate" part easily, it does not mean that it can stream data. Since relational databases are consistent (while mongodb is "eventually" consistent), the whole batch of document is retained in memory somewhere, either in the DB itself, in the server-side application, or both, until transferred to the next consumer. So it does not solve the memory consumption problem at all.